# How to call python function which has arguments in date format?

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have the function below, and the problem is that when I call the function I get the error saying `ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp` (unfortunately, pc wouldn't allow me copy the full error message though, because pc at work is just built that way :(  ). Anyway, here's my code:

```
def ao_year(start, end):
    ##This fucntion selects all columns and rows, between two selected 
    ##dates from 'event_start_date_time' column
    return ao_paths_2009.loc[(ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] >= 
         '{}') & (ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] <= '{}')]

#Calling the function
ao_year_2009 = ao_year('2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')
print(ao_year_2009.info())
```

I've already tried  `.strftime('%d/%m%)Y'` without success.

Comment: Update: I don't know why comments is cutting off first line f my code, here it is:

`def ao_year(start, end):
 #This fucntion selects all columns and rows, between two selected dates from 
        # 'event_start_date_time' column:
 return ao_paths_2009.loc[(ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] >= '{}') & 
 (ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] <= '{}')]
#Calling the function
ao_year_2009 = ao_year('2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')
print(ao_year_2009.info())`

Comment: I don't know much about the database or what ao_paths_2009 is but if you just need to convert the string to a timestamp `print(datetime.strptime('2009-01-01', '%Y-%M-%d'))` works for dates in the form '2009-01-01', '2009-12-31'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# option 1: using strongly typed argument
from datetime import date
import pandas as pd


def ao_year(start: date, end: date):
    return ao_paths_2009.loc[
        (ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] >= start) & (ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] <= end)]


try:
    _list = {'event_start_date_time': ['2009-01-01 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-02 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-03 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-04 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-05 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-06 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-07 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-08 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-09 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-10 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-11 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-12 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-13 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-14 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-02-15 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-02-16 12:44:33 PM']}
    ao_paths_2009 = pd.DataFrame(data=_list)
    ao_year_2009 = ao_year('2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')
    # print(ao_year_2009.info())
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
        print(ao_year_2009)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# option 2: pass function param as string convert to datetime
import pandas as pd


def ao_year(start, end):
    start = pd.to_datetime(start).date()
    end = pd.to_datetime(end).date()
    return ao_paths_2009.loc[
        (ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] >= start) & (ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] <= end)]


try:
    _list = {'event_start_date_time': ['2009-01-01 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-02 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-03 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-04 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-05 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-06 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-07 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-08 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-09 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-10 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-11 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-12 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-13 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-01-14 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-02-15 12:44:33 PM',
                                       '2009-02-16 12:44:33 PM']}
    ao_paths_2009 = pd.DataFrame(data=_list)
    ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(ao_paths_2009['event_start_date_time'])
    ao_year_2009 = ao_year('2009-01-01', '2009-12-31')
    with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
        print(ao_year_2009)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```